# Changing default header for JSON data in Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I've noticed that using Gin to return a response like this:

```
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, jsonData)
```

automatically creates the following header:

```
application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Is it possible to modify the header somehow to just return

```
application/json
```

I'd rather take this approach than splitting the string at the `;`

Comment: Why do you have to split the string? You should be able to accept a valid Content-Type header.

Answer (score 9):

1. Modify the source code to [remove the `; charset=utf-8` string](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/render/json.go#L22), or
2. Have a wrapper function which manually sets `Content-Type` before the `gin.Context.JSON` call:

   ```
   func JSON(c *gin.Context, code int, obj interface{}) {
       c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
       c.JSON(code, obj)
   }

   // ...

   JSON(c, http.StatusOK, jsonData)
   ```

Comment: I needed to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and this solution worked flawlessly to me (I'm using `c.XML()`, but the concept is pretty much the same). Thanks!

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn You can try this out: [https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors), a middleware which can add some basic cors headers.

Comment: @Zhwt oh that's even better... thanks so much! I've filed it as a `TODO()` on my code, it's far better to use a much neater library to accomplish the same thing with middleware...

Answer (score 0):

You can add new headers in the request like this :

```
c.Request.Header.Add("x-request-id", requestID)
```